# Get the position of an element

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having trouble trying to scroll up a tableView when the user start editing a UITextField displayed in one of the cells.

My problem is that I can't find a way to know the position of the UITextField in the view. If I try to do activeTextField.frame.origin.y, I get the position of the TextField inside the cell, but not inside the tableView.

The way I build the view is the following :
I've got a TableViewController, which creates cells using a custom class that initializes the UITextField. Then my TableViewController set the UITextField delegate to itself, so I can trigger the textFieldDidBeginEditing event. But if I try to NSLog the y origin of the TextField, I always get the same value for each UITextField, which is its position in the cell.

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to work out which cell has been tapped, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what is the absolute position of the UITextField in the TableView, so I can scroll my tableView to make sure the field is still visible when the keyboard shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always confusing with these coordinate system changes ...

This should work to get you the point in the table view coordinate system:

```
CGPoint textFieldCenter = textField.center;
CGPoint pointInTableView = [tableView convertPoint:textFieldCenter fromView:textField.superview];
```

If you want to have it in a different view, you should replace tableView with the view you want to have the coordinate in.

And if you want to get the cell in the table the textField was in:

```
NSIndexPath* path = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTableView];
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Comment: i had some problem of getting coordinates of view in scrollview but this solved my problem

Comment: I had a complicated issue that needed fixing, this did the trick. Imagine a pickerview inside a popoverView inside a VERY large static table cell, inside a container view that isn't full screen! (The designer behind this idea has been sacked!)

Answer (score 2):

To get the position of your textfield should use the UIView method [convertRect:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

> convertRect:toView: Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s
>   coordinate system to that of another view.
>
> - (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view

example :

```
CGRect textFieldFrame = [self.tableview convertRect:yourTextField.frame toView:self.view];
```

Comment: If I try to do this, I get the same result. 
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldFrame = [self.tableView convertRect:textField.frame toView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"Position : %f", textFieldFrame.origin.y);
}

Comment: It depends of your view hierrachy, but this is definitely the way to go. Have a look at these methods in the doc, you can also try convertRect:fromView: , something like  CGRect textFieldFrame = [self.view convertRect:yourTextField.frame fromView:self.tableview];

Answer (score 1):

this should help you out 
[This is simple and easy way of doing what you want](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using this method :

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

When you prompt the keyboard, scroll the tableView to the selected cell it should bring the cell to the top of the screen.

Comment: Use UITableViewDelegate. You have a method that gives you the indexPath of the row that have been selected. (- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath)

Comment: Yep, but the method isn't called if the user click on the textfield that is in the cell, instead of the cell itself. Just tried it, and the method is only triggered if i click elsewhere in the cell.

Comment: Hum, interesting. Your TextField is on the contentView property of the UITableViewCell? Do you have an other way of getting the position of the Cell?

Comment: I've got a custom class for my UITableViewCell, where I create my UITextField this way : textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0, 9.0, 120.0, 23.0)];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CGPoint locationinView=[cellView convertPoint:location fromView:tableView];
```

here location is the point of textField in cellView.

Comment: Not sure I understand you on this. I do know the position of my textfield in the cellView. What I want to know is the position of the textfield in the tableView, or the index of the cell where the TextField is